# Unable to ping/connect to azure sql server from sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, azure-sql-database

I created a database in azure and assigned a new server to it. I entered my ip address in the firewall and tried to connect to the server in Sql Server Management Studio but no success. I tried to ping the FQDN of the server server.database.windows.net but no success.
I searched the problem and I found that the server cannot be pinged 
[click here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b32a0597-8abd-497a-af54-14cb5102831a/cannot-ping-sql-azure-server). Can you please help me in connecting to the SQL server or database from SSMS on my machine?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with our company firewall. The port 1433 was blocked on the firewall. After removing the outgoing and incoming restrictions on firewall the SMSS started working.